# ASP.NET 5 published folder contains wrong (old) DLLs

Tags: visual-studio, publishing

**Framework Dependent Publish setup**

- Publishing to local folder
- Delete existing files set to True
- Configuration is Release
- Target Framework is net5.0
- Target Runtime is win-x64
- Project's bin folder is not included in project (could this be the
  issue?)

The DLLs in my project's bin/Debug/net5.0 and bin/Release/net5.0 are the proper versions, but the versions of some DLLs that end up my published folder *(Microsoft.EntityFramework.Core.dll for example)* are earlier *(older)* versions.

I had to manually copy the DLLs from my project's bin folder over to IIS.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Deleting everything under the project's obj folder seems to have solved this issue.